What is "horror show of rule salad" intended to mean?
I've stumbled upon a puzzling phrase that goes:

It reads like a bad faith thought experiment you’d use to shoot down
someone’s suggestion: “Oh, what do you want us to do, [that horror
show of rule salad]?!”

What is this part "[that horror show of rule salad]" supposed to mean? Horror show, rule salad... just don't get it.
The whole post can be found here https://www.pentadact.com/2022-11-10-five-problems-with-chess/

It’s the writer’s view of the game of chess.
As a horror show, it is supposedly frightening.
“Rule salad” means a mixture of rules that makes, to the writer, little sense.
Salads are collections of ingredients that need not be in related quantities.  A “word salad” is a collection of words that don’t seem to make sense or be related—just mixed up words.  The writer simply makes the analogy to chess rules.
It would be courteous to provide a more extensive quote and a link to help volunteers reply to your questions.

For those interested, this question and answer cover the origin of "word salad".

Thank you very much for clarification as well as to @StuartF for the link to the similar problem! As for more extensive quote, will try to do that in future.

While this explains what was intended by the author, it should not be left unsaid that it was a very clumsy mixed metaphor.
